# Dev Build and Tasks Directory and DataObject?

Tags: silverstripe

Where exactly is the dev/build and dev/tasks directories in a Silverstripe installation? Is is in the Framework directory?  Or should I create them if they are missing? Also how do I create an instance of a ORM Dataobject without using create?

Comment: Are you trying to understand what happens when you add /dev/build to the URL?

Comment: yes, and also wanted to see the actual php files called, wanted to add some functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are no directories, they are in the URL and then the URL gets parsed by silverstripe, see in your .htaccess for something like...

```
RewriteRule .* framework/main.php?url=%1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

...this line (and some previous) indicate that the URL is passed to the main.php and then it is parsed.

This process is called URL rewriting there is a good introduction here https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

Silverstripe calls this configuration routing (so route certain URLS to certain controllers) and is documented here https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.2/developer_guides/controllers/routing/

The "dev" url segment maps to DevelopmentAdmin in the routes.yml